# My blog "page" used to show a list of posts, but now it's just showing the page content?

Tags: posts, pages, templates

I used to have a page called "Blog" with dummy content (it said "hello world" or similar). Off the menu there was a link to www.mydomain.com/blog and this used to fire up index.php and list recent *posts*. The hello world content of the blog *page* never showed up. And in any case, the Blog page was set to Draft.

This was just how I wanted it, even though I couldn't work out how the WordPress loop within index.php was managing to show *posts* and not the *hello world*. Here's what the loop looks like in index.php:

```
 if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        if (is_search() && ($post->post_type=='page')) continue; ?>
        <div class="box">
         <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <h2><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
```

The site was running fine. Recently, for not special reason, I noticed that the Blog *page* still existed albeit set to *Draft*. To tidy up a bit I figured I'd delete the page. After all it seemingly wasn't required.

As soon as I deleted it, going to www.mydomain.com/blog resulted in a 404. Yikes. I quickly restored the Blog page. It showed "Hello world". I deleted it again. *404*. I recreated it as a Draft (in case that was crucial). *404*. I published it. *Hello World*. I cannot get my list of posts back.

I have a complete copy of the site on another server, with the behaviour I wanted to restore (mydomain.com/blog firing up index.php with a list of recent posts). I have reproduced the exact above steps with the same results.

Whatever I try (on either server) I cannot get back to how it was, with mydomain.com/blog firing up index.php with a list of recent posts.

While I concede that whatever setup I had before was fragile and perhaps not the "correct" way to setup a theme, it did work as it stood, and I would love to know how I can restore it, without having to code a new template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can - sort of - solve my problem by cheating.

One of the reasons I don't want to dig around in the code in index.php is that it serves both as a sort of homepage for the blog and also as a search results page (in this site searching through posts is the only kind of search we care about).

So on the menu I can point the href for the Blog link to `mydomain.com/?s` instead of `mydomain.com/blog`. This shows the old list of posts and does solve the problem with no coding needed.

But I'd still love to know why it *used* to work with `mydomain.com/blog`.